# Responsive Web Design Automatically Zoomed Some Times

Tags: responsive-design

i made a responsive web page with media query.

view on mobile device it auto zoom though i have not defined to zoom.

while used meta content "width=device-width" it looks like it is viewing on desktop browser after that user have to zoom out to see the actual view.

Comment: Sounds like you have a fixed width value on the container for your page

Comment: issue has been solved with meta tag properties.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the below meta tag in head

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
```